# 3D Textured Object rotate on swipe

Tags: iphone, ipad, 3d

I'm new to the 3D subject for iPhone, iPad and it may be a broader question...

Not looking for a specific answer...

Basically rotating a 3D object along y axis and a bit limited on x axis...

What exactly any 3rd party libraries for frameworks should I be studying to accomplish the above....

Above also involves working with a 3D professional who will provide me a 3D model along with the texture... where to read about mapping the texture over the object.

Again... not looking for a specific answer... please guide whatever you can....

Comment: Read [this book](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/).

Comment: Be careful if using that book. It has some really fundamental errors in the code for very fundamental things like matrices and quaternions and basically does some things backwards. Details here: http://oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596804831

Comment: Not looking for specific answer? :) This is stackoverflow. Specific questions and answers is what we do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use Open GL ES. It's not third party, it comes with iOS.

Search the web for lots of info and tutorials, e.g.:
[3D Graphics Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147628/3d-graphics-tutorials)